# Executing this API call. Sending json as parameter?

Tags: php, json

I am working with API called "Active Collab", I am trying to build a custom report.

`API::get('/users/3/time-records/filtered-by-date')`

```
Query Parameters:
{
    "from": "2014-12-01",
    "to": "2014-12-31"
}
```

I don't know how to do this...

I tried `API::get('/users/3/time-records/'.$filtered-by-date)`

```
$filter-by-date = {
        "from": "2014-12-01",
        "to": "2014-12-31"
    }

and

$filter-by-date = json_encode({
        "from": "2014-12-01",
        "to": "2014-12-31"
    });
```

it just never works.. I must be doing the filter-by-date wrong, however I just don't know what to do here.

Thanks

EDITED:

## Tried this as well

`$filter_by_date = json_encode(["from"=>"2014-12-01","to"=> "2014-12-31"]);`

```
API::get('/users/'.$request->get('employee').'/time-records/filter_by_date')
```

Still nothing..

Top of my post is how API doc shows it I just have no idea how to execute that...

Comment: You can't use JS object notation in PHP - you have to use arrays (either with `array()` or `[]` in 5.4+). You need to use the original url but send a different request like your last piece of code using `json_encode`

Comment: @h2ooooooo could you show me what you are thinking please I am losing my mind here :)

Comment: Instead of {, use [ and instead of }, use]. You cannot use this curly bracket notation in php. You're probably thinking javascript.

Comment: You never tell it to use your variable. I don't know the API class so I don't know how to pass this, but it's probably GET. url.php?from=2014-12-01&to=2014-12-31

Comment: I tried that as well and it didn't work I forgot to add it into a OP.

Comment: @h2ooooooo figured it out.. its in the OP.. thanks

Comment: Instead of editing your question to contain the answer, you can and should post it as an actual Answer to your question and mark it as accepted. Don't worry, self-answers are very accepted here. I have rolled back the edit to preserve the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is the answer that was given in the edit to the question by the OP*

---

If anyone else is working with ActiveCollab API, here is how to pass the variable.

```
API::get('/users/'.$userID.'/time-records/'. http_build_query(['from' => $this->from, 'to' => $this->to]);
```

Comment: Had to make a small change to my answer, it didn't crash but it didn't work for some reason correctly this one works 100%!